# Python 3.8 order of import modules and custom modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm confused about import order and use.
As you can see in the code below, in main I first import psycopg2.
THEN I import data_connect (that has dependency on psycopg2), so two questions:
(1) Why doesn't the interpreter see that I already imported psycopg2?
(2) How do I fix this?
Thanks!

Error message:

```
File "C:\home\partscobra.com\wwwroot\data_connect.py" in data_connect:
db_conn = psycopg2.connect(...
NameError: name 'psycopg2' is not defined"
```

main.py:

```
import psycopg2
from data_connect import data_connect, data_cursor
#error here
[snip]
```

data_connect.py:

```
def data_connect():
    t_host = "blahblahblah"
    t_port = "5432"
    t_dbname = "inventory"
    t_user = "remote"
    t_pw = "blahblahblah"
    db_conn = psycopg2.connect(
        host=t_host,
        port=t_port,
        dbname=t_dbname,
        user=t_user,
        password=t_pw
        )
    db_conn.autocommit=True
    return db_conn

def data_cursor():
    db_conn = data_connect()
    db_cursor = db_conn.cursor()
    return db_cursor
```

Comment: Add an import inside `data_connect.py`. Stuff you import gets added to the global namespace of the current module (e.g. `main`), not every module (e.g. `data_connect`).

Comment: Each file needs to be able to load by itself (even if it doesn't *do anything meaningful*) by itself - it can't expect to be "rescued" by another file that's importing it. In some other languages, this would merely be a bad idea; in Python, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It works in some IDE (Spyder) where running a program that imports stuff then running your module for testing works even though the module lacks imports. That is why you need to clear all the variables stored before running a code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stuff you import gets added to the current namespace (in this case the global namespace of the `main` module), not to every module (e.g. `data_connect`).

If you `import psycopg2` in `data_connect.py` then `psycopg2` will be added to the global namespace of your `data_connect` module.